# Not able to save Calender Date in Data base in java

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, date

I am trying to save date in database. Receiving the Date from partner system in `XML` and the jar file which is providing setter and getter methods for that `XML` tag is of

```
 java.util.Calender type
```

This I need to save as Date type in my code. I am trying to use `getTime()` method but its not saving. I am not getting any exception but value is not storing in Database.

java.util.Calender ls; `ls.getDate()` is the method which getting date from `XML` Tag its inside jar file

```
 XML tag is <v2:EffDate>2013-12-01T00:00:00Z</v2:Effdate>

    Date date = (Date)ls.getEffDate().getTime(); // ls is the object and converting Calander to Date
```

I also tried -

```
    Date date = ls.getEffDate().getTime();
```

now setting this value to DB

```
    Class SaveDate sd = new Savedate();
    sd.setEffdate(date);
```

when saving it as DomainObject for simple form controller of Spring its not reflecting in DB
other values are saving fine for same object

hibernate mapping is like

```
    <property name = "effDate" type = "java.util.Date"> <column name = "Effective_Date"/></property >
```

`EFFECTIVE_DATE` is of Type Date in `DataBase`

what is the way to save it ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It works for me..

Pass your `calendar.getTime()` to this method.

```
public static java.sql.Timestamp convertToSQLDate(Date date) {
    java.sql.Timestamp sqlDate = null;
    if (date != null) {
        sqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }
    return sqlDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
java.sql.Date
```

instead of

```
java.util.Date
```

Change that in hbm mappings as well.